# Unable to connect to spring cloud consul (can't set host/port)

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file, spring-cloud-consul

I am trying to connect to a `consul` server from a `Spring boot` application, which fails because spring cloud consul doesn't seem to read my host configuration.

> Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   localhost:8500 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]
>   failed: Connection refused: connect

The documentation says that we need to set the consul host from the `bootstrap.properties/yml` file. I have tried setting `spring.cloud.consul.host` in using by `yml` and `properties` format:

`spring.cloud.consul.host=myhost` (with the appropriate format for `.properties` vs. `.yml`)

or

`spring.cloud.consul.host=myhost` - fun fact, this works correctly when passing in as a program argument.

**Dependencies**:

- spring-boot-starter-parent - 2.0.4.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-starter-consul-all - 1.3.2.RELEASE

Comment: Have you checked that consul port is pingable with something like `telnet localhost 8500` ?

Comment: Are you sure the properties file you're setting this in is actually being read?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud consul starter 1.3.x is not compatible with spring boot 2.x so it may be issue. Try with spring boot 1.5.x version instead.

Works for me with both Finchley (2.0.x) and Greenwich cloud version (2.1.x) and spring boot 2.0.x. More [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud). Compatibility matrix can be found at the bottom of page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your bootstrap.yml file is not getting loaded. Do you have the spring-cloud starter as a dependency (pom.xml if using Maven to build)? If it's included then the issue is probably to do with how you are starting the app. Are you running from the command line, or using Intellij/Eclipe to run it? There is probably something about the runtime environment that is causing the bootstrap.yml to not get loaded.

Please provide more details around how you are starting this app if you are still having issues with this.